# Bower install from URL returning corrupted file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bower

I'm trying to do a bower install from a URL for a resource on S3.  Running the following command

`bower install --save-dev hellosign=http://s3.amazonaws.com/cdn.hellofax.com/js/embedded.js`

will install a corrupted file in the directory hellosign/index.js.  the file looks like this: https://gist.github.com/razorman8669/0448a681cf922d000a2a

Why is it that bower is installing this file as corrupted? if you access the file directly it's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
curl -vvv http://s3.amazonaws.com/cdn.hellofax.com/js/embedded.js
...
> GET /cdn.hellofax.com/js/embedded.js HTTP/1.1
...
...
< Content-Encoding: gzip
```

It's not corrupting it. It's just that the file it's actually gzipped. Bet you that if you rename the file and try to extract it you'll get the right content.

Store the file uncompressed or give it a proper name so that bower can figure out that it has to extract it (it's kind of dumb that it does not figure this one out by itself).

Any browser that's pointer at that location will figure out it's compressed and actually display it properly.

Comment: seems like bower doesn't play well with gzipped files... though it's on the radar https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/1004